# SSRS Report Render report in PDF Via URL

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS2016 Report that I'm able to connect to in the browser:
http://vmbksa69901mcz/reports_ssrs1d/report/DAS/CDO_Suite/AccruedInterestRpt

But I want to be able to export to pdf by the url. This article states that this is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access

So, when I try to put in this url:
http://vmbksa69901mcz/reports_ssrs1d?/DAS/CDO_Suite/AccruedInterestRpt&rs:Format=PDF

It does not work.. It just brings me to the home page of the SSRS Site, and changes the url to: 
http://vmbksa69901mcz/reports_ssrs1d/browse/

I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't asking you to download the PDF in the bottom of your browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% Sure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use a URL to pass commands you need to use the `Web Service URL` reportserver path in the URL not the web portals URL.

If you run the Reporting Services Configuration Manager and look under "Web Service URL" you see a different address.

By default the web portal (SSRS home page as you called it) will be at http://myServer/Reports

But the Web Service URL by default is
http://myServer/Reportserver

Comment: great man, i have been missing this from last 3 hours , many thanks to you.

Comment: This answer saved me, thank you very much. But do you know if there's a way to rename the file name to passed parameter via the URL? For ex: right now the file download as my report's name, but is it possible to replace the file name from "SalesOrder.pdf" to something like "218375.pdf" dynamically via parameter value? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to @Alan's answer, my report was for exporting to excel :

A report with url : 
http://myservername/Reports/report/myserverSSRSUpgrade/PCM%20Allocation%20Report?DateFrom=04%2F01%2F2018&DateTo=04%2F30%2F2018&ParentID=46416&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML

gets converted to

http://myservername/ReportServer?%2fmyserverSSRSUpgrade%2fPCM+Allocation+Report&DateFrom=04%2F01%2F2018&DateTo=04%2F30%2F2018&ParentID=46416&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML

Have a close look at the placement of `?` character in both the query strings.