# Save SSRS report as PDF in .net Winforms app without rendering report

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, reporting-services, reportviewer

I've read a lot of posts about this and I think there's an underlying issue I'm missing.

I want to be able to take the URI of my report on SSRS, capture the stream and save it as a PDF. Fairly straight forward. However if I use a report viewer control in my form and specify the server URI and path in the GUI properties as:

**URI**: `\\\SQLReports\Reports`

**Path**: `\Test\TestReport`

The viewer errors saying it cant connect to the server, error 404.

If I use a webclient and

```
WebClient.Downloaddata("http://sqlreports/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fTEST%2ftestreport)
```

I get a file and data but its just the HTML of the webpage, unsurprisingly.

Is there something else I'm missing here? Version differences between report viewer of the SSRS server and my local machine? (running the compiled `exe` on the server has the same issue) adding the `rs command render = PDF` to the URI doesn't change the outcome either.

I'm at a loss. I'm sure there's an easier way to capture the SSRS report as a PDF and write out the memory stream but as the PDF data and not HTML markup.

Comment: If you put `&rs:Format=PDF` on the end of that URL does it do what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. No it still grabs a HTML file. If I open the file with notepad I get HTML. Same for changing the format to excel or csv.

Comment: If you plug that URL straight into a browser, what do you get?

Comment: The report displayed in browser.

Comment: OK I think your URL is incorrect - look a the URL format here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705408/ssrs-report-render-report-in-pdf-via-url The SSRS URL API is very confusing!

Comment: Ahhhhh that seems to produce something - now to just get it to fit the report onto one page rather than splitting the columns. Many thanks! Can I mark a comment as the answer, you wonderful wonderful man?

Comment: So pleased I could help. I"m just going to mark this a duplicate if that's OK.