# Corrupted PDF from direct url in SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am trying to generate a direct url to my report so it can be downloaded as PDF instead of redirect to the report UI.
If I paste the url on the browser it just redirects me to the report's page.
I found 2 solutions to my problem but both generate a corrupted pdf.

```
        public ActionResult GetReportingData()
        {
            var theURL = "http://servername/Reports_DomainName/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMQMS2_TST%2fReportTest&year=2019&rs:Format=PDF";

            WebClient Client = new WebClient();
            Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password");

            byte[] myDataBuffer = Client.DownloadData(theURL);

            var filename = "Test.pdf";
            var path = "C:\\Test";

            var fileLocation = path + "\\" + filename;

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, myDataBuffer);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Case");
        }
```

```
        public ActionResult GetReportingData()
        {
            var url = "http://servername/Reports_DomainName/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMQMS2_TST%2fReportTest&year=2019&rs:Format=PDF";
            try
            {
                url = url.Replace("\n", "");
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password");
                request.Credentials = credentials;

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Case");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

This is the link for the asnwer: [SSRS Report Render report in PDF Via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705408/ssrs-report-render-report-in-pdf-via-url)

Basically I was using the web portal url (wrong) instead of the web service url (correct):

Original (wrong url): http://servername/**Reports**_DomainName/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMQMS2_TST%2fReportTest&year=2019&rs:Format=PDF

Correct url: http://servername/**ReportServer**_DomainName/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMQMS2_TST%2fReportTest&year=2019&rs:Format=PDF

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with generating the PDF from data (via SSRS LocalReport), which gives me full control.  However, what happens if you tweak your first option like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetReportingData()
{
    var theURL = "http://servername/Reports_DomainName/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fMQMS2_TST%2fReportTest&year=2019&rs:Format=PDF";

    try
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password");

        byte[] data = Client.DownloadData(theURL);

        return new FileContentResult(data, "PDF") { FileDownloadName = String.Format("SomeReport_{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")) };       
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This should prompt you to save the file from browser.  Then try opening the file to see if it's still corrupt.  It's possible the URL you're calling to gen the PDF is returning other noise in the response content and therefore not just a byte array of the report/pdf.